# Build failure - Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'block'

Tags: jekyll, octopress

Been using Octopress for some days now. However recently met this error when using the following code block in my post:

```
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The error returned is

```
Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'block'
```

Looked around but cannot find a solution to this.

Why am I receiving a Liquid Exception?

Comment: If you are trying to syntax highlight a codeblock, the [docs](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/codeblock/) use the full word codeblock (as in `{% codeblock %}` instead of just `{% block %}`)

Comment: There is no `block` tag in  liquid.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but for reference, the liquid template language in Jekyll is still rather limited. I've run across references to liquid templates with `extends` and `block`, but Jekyll doesn't support these tags.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `block` plugin.  That's the standard error you get when you are trying to use a plugin or YAML command that doesn't exist.

I think you may want one of the following:

```
{% blockquote %}
Four scores and sever years ago.
{% endblockquote %}
```

Or

```
{% codeblock %}
$ rake generate
$ rake deploy
{% endcodeblock %}
```

You should really REALLY read the documentation at Octopress.  It lists everything it comes with, especially for the basics of blogging:

## http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/plugins/

It has many many MANY options for just those two I posted above.  For exammple, I often define the author of my blockquotes:

```
{% blockquote Abraham Lincoln http://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/speeches/gettysburg.htm The Gettysburg Address %}
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, 
{% endblockquote %}
```

And that would show up very pretty with a nice `<cite>` at the bottom, with *The Gettysburg Address* as a link to that webpage.